# Вычислить долю каждого от всех

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица SQL my_dataset:

```
Sex    Params
M         4
F         29
F         11
M         33
F         8
F         6
```

В одном запросу нужно вычислить долю записей для каждого Sex. Код

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql_str = '''SELECT sex AS gender, 
            (COUNT(sex)*100.0 / COUNT(*)) AS gender_counter
            FROM hr_dataset
            GROUP BY gender
            ORDER BY gender;'''

gender_counter = pd.read_sql_query(sql_str, conn)
```

возвращает

```
Sex   Params
F      100
M      100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT 100 * SUM((Sex = 'M')::INT) / COUNT(Sex) percent_m,
       100 * SUM((Sex = 'F')::INT) / COUNT(Sex) percent_f
FROM test;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1e786f63b15f36d957c146bdcef96edd

Comment: Отнюдь. Ругается на типы:
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @AndrewTim А у Вас часом не постгресс, а?

Comment: Да, действительно постгресс.

Comment: @AndrewTim Откорректировал для PostgerSQL-12. PS. Добавьте соотв. тег к своему вопросу.

Comment: @Akina, запись `(Sex = 'M')::INT` в постгресе - это эквивалент `CASE WHEN Sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Угу. Почти. Только на NULL среагирует иначе.